# Images and CSS are not working on github.io pages

Tags: github

i had a older portfolio page in this link. Now i create new updated one. But the CSS and Images can't work. I cleared the caches but didn't work.

repo link : https://github.com/Remonhasan/remonhasan.github.io

Comment: Change your request `http` to `https` https://github.com/Remonhasan/remonhasan.github.io/pull/1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should pay attention to the console log:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://remonhasan.github.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,800,700,400italic|PT+Serif:400,400italic'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

And another way, I found the link https://remonhasan.github.io/#portfolio is no problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in that https://remonhasan.github.io/portfolio/ seem to return a completely different webpage to https://remonhasan.github.io/

I am no expert on GH pages or how you even get a url/something to return a completely different webpage (maybe I am missing something) but on your page https://remonhasan.github.io/ you have references to https://remonhasan.github.io/portfolio/image.png and I believe, that https://remonhasan.github.io/portfolio/ not opening the folder, but some website, is what is causing your issue.

I could be completely wrong too. But I did check all the other obvious things like capitilaization issues and such...